# Changing styling of elements inside of an iframe with jQuery

Tags: jquery, iframe

I'm trying to change the color of an element inside an iframe like this:

```
<iframe width="1000" height="700" scrolling="no" id="prev" src="http://matchesfashion.com">your browser needs to be updated.
</iframe>

$(function(){
  $("#prev").contents().find(".inner-border").css("color", "red");
});
```

On CodePen: http://codepen.io/itsthomas/pen/oXpdrp?editors=101

But it doesn't work. Any idea why?

Many thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer: No!

Browsers handle domain security on the principle of **[Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)** and the **[laws of cross domain communication](http://softwareas.com/cross-domain-communication-with-iframes)**.

Have a look at an interesting read on the creationg of read-write JS APIs on this blog post [How To Build A Read/Write JavaScript API](http://piecesofrakesh.blogspot.com/2007/11/how-to-build-readwrite-javascript-api.html)